# Python: Simple Histogram From DataFrame Gone Awry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, histogram

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
    pageviews   type
0   48.0    original
1   181.0   licensed
2   50.0    original
3   17.0    original
...
```

I want to create two histograms, one for the "original" type and one for the "licensed" type.

So I do:

```
ax = df.hist(by='type')
plt.show()
```

And I get this:

[image]

That's a start, but it's way too zoomed out and I don't know why the height is uniform (it's just a single rectangle).  I thought this might have something to do with how zoomed out I am, so I ran:

```
for plot in ax:
    plot.set_xlim(0, 400000)
```

And then I get this, which also seems no better:

[image]

I just want a normal looking histogram of the pageviews per type :(

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `df.hist(by='type', bins=20)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ax = df.groupby("type").sum().plot(kind="bar")
ax2 = ax.twinx()
for r in ax.patches[len(df):]:
    r.set_transform(ax2.transData)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 2);
```

Comment: Just did this but what does the y-axis represent?  It looks like it ranges from 0-2 on the right side and 0-1.4 on the left...

Comment: the y-axis should represent your pageviews. this code above will give you one chart with both categories on the x-axis and the respective number of pageviews on the y-axis.